# Unexpected XQueryException: Port is currently in use error in sbt console

Tags: scala, playframework, marklogic, marklogic-7

I am using **Marklogic 7.0-5** along with **Play 2.2.6** in my project.
I am running **run 9002** command on sbt console where my project repo path points on my machine.It prompts me with the following message

**Cannot load the JNotify native library (no jnotify in java.library.path)
Play will check file changes for each request, so expect degraded reloading performace.**

and then displays following information

**[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9002
(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)**

After this when I hit localhost:9002 in a browser it gives 
Unexpected exception
XQueryException: Port is currently in use

and the stacktrace is as below

```
No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
->com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: Port is currently in use
     com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.ServerExceptionHandler.handleResponse(ServerExceptionHandler.java:34)
     com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.EvalRequestController.serverDialog(EvalRequestController.java:83)
     com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.AbstractRequestController.runRequest(AbstractRequestController.java:86)
     com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequestInternal(SessionImpl.java:388)
     com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequest(SessionImpl.java:371)
     com.springer.adis.ingest.marklogic.XccManager.execute(XccManager.scala:12)
     com.springer.adis.ingest.marklogic.XccManager.executeToSingleString(XccManager.scala:16)
     com.springer.adis.ingest.service.MarklogicService.execXquery(MarklogicService.scala:33)
     com.springer.adis.ingest.service.MarklogicService$$anonfun$1.apply(MarklogicService.scala:59)
     com.springer.adis.ingest.service.MarklogicService$$anonfun$1.apply(MarklogicService.scala:59)
     scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
     scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
     com.springer.adis.ingest.service.MarklogicService.exec(MarklogicService.scala:64)
     Global$.runDBSetup(Global.scala:53)
     Global$.onStart(Global.scala:24)
     play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(GlobalSettings.scala:203)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
     play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:139)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110)
     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:102)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I tried killing process which is using the same port but it still gives me the same error.

Your help is truly appreciated,Thanks.

Comment: Please, add the code for your `Global.onStart` and `Global.runDBSetup`.

Comment: @marcospereira Below are the required codes:-  `override def onStart(app: Application) {
    val configService = new ConfigService
    val exceptionFileWriter: ExceptionFileWriter = new ExceptionFileWriter
    runDBSetup(configService, exceptionFileWriter)
    reloadModulesAndQueries(configService, exceptionFileWriter)
    reloadStopWordsXML(configService, exceptionFileWriter)
    setupCronJobs(configService, exceptionFileWriter)
  }`

Comment: `private def runDBSetup(configService: ConfigService, exceptionFileWriter: ExceptionFileWriter) = {
    Logger.info("Executing setup scripts...")
    val adisDataService = new AdisDataService(configService.xccUrl, configService, exceptionFileWriter)
    adisDataService.exec(true, "scripts/setup/")
  }`